# How can I build and deploy a shared library within a sub project using CMake?

Tags: c++, installation, cmake, makefile, build

I have a larger project which already has a CMakeLists.txt file and that builds fine. I'd like to create a C++ library from a file named `interface.h` within `sub_project/include/` and the larger project will link to this shared library.

The folder hierarchy looks like this:

```
main_project
├── build
├── include
├── src
├── sub_project     (the shared library code)
│   ├── build
│   ├── include
│   │   ├── interface.h
│   ├── src
│   │   ├── interface.cpp
│   │── CMakeLists.txt
│── CMakeLists.txt
```

interface.h:

```
#include <iostream>

void zzz()
{
    std::cout << "zzz() called" << std::endl;
}
```

interface.cpp (I need a source file to create a shared library?)

```
#include <include/interface.h>
```

This is my new CMakeLists.txt to create the shared library:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.17.2)
project(mylib VERSION 1.0.1 DESCRIPTION "mylib description")
add_library(mylib SHARED src/interface.cpp)
set_target_properties(mylib PROPERTIES VERSION ${PROJECT_VERSION})
set_target_properties(mylib PROPERTIES PUBLIC_HEADER include/interface.h)
target_include_directories(mylib PRIVATE include)
target_include_directories(mylib PRIVATE src)

include(GNUInstallDirs)

install(TARGETS mylib
    LIBRARY DESTINATION parent/build
    PUBLIC_HEADER DESTINATION ${CMAKE_INSTALL_INCLUDEDIR})
```

I'm trying to install the library to my `parent/build` folder.

However, when I run `cmake ..` and `make` I get:

```
fatal error: include/interface.h: No such file or directory
```

I am not sure where I should put the public headers? The shared library will only be used by `main_project`.

Comment: You are missing the call to `target_include_directories`. PUBLIC_HEADER doesn't set include directories.

Comment: @Tsyvarev thanks. I just added them, retried but still get the error, so i've included them in the CMakeLists.txt above.

Comment: For being able to use `#include <include/interface.h>`, you need to include `sub_project` directory.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be specifying the include directory for the shared library with [`target_include_directories`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/target_include_directories.html) like

```
target_include_directories(mylib PUBLIC include)
```

And then in your cpp file, include it like:

```cpp
#include <interface.h>
```

If you actually want "include" to be part of the path of what you `#include`, then do `target_include_directories(mylib PUBLIC .)` instead. From what I know though, it's more conventional to not do things that way.

> The shared library will only be used by main_project.

If your shared library will never be used outside of the context of the containing project, I don't see the need to make it its own project (with the [`project()`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/project.html) call) or build and install the subproject. You can just use [`add_subdirectory`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/add_subdirectory.html).

As for installation, you can read about how to do that in [the Mastering CMake book's chapter on installing files](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/book/mastering-cmake/chapter/Install.html), or by reading the reference docs for [`install(TARGETS ...)`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/install.html#targets).

Comment: Use add_subdirectory the CMakeLists.txt file in the top-level folder? And just remove the `project` line in my new CMakeLIsts.txt?

Comment: @intrigued_66 yep.